# How do I decompress data coming from a MS SQL VarBinary and save as file? (in PHP)

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve files from a Microsoft SQL varbinary field in php. These files were compressed using IO.Compression.DeflateStream() in a Visual Studio program before being inserted into the database.

I can get the files out of the database, but I'm not sure how to decompress the files:

```
 <?php
//assume that I already made the connection

$sql = "SELECT [FileData], [contentType] FROM dbo.Files where [FileGUID]='DAB88A50-E2C3-E311-A2D2-005056930304'";

$stmt= sqlsrv_query($conn , $sql);


if( $stmt === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}

$result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$filename = "test.pdf";
$X = $result['FileData'];

$contentType=  $result['ContentType'];
$filename=  $result['Filename'];


header("Content-Type:    $contentType; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");  //File name extension was wrong
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");



//$X =  unpack('H*hex', $X);

echo $X;

?>
```

The PHP above gets the file, but it's still in the compressed format.

In VB I can get the get file decompressed using the following code:

```
 Dim Decompressed As Byte()
            Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(b)

                Dim msOut As New IO.MemoryStream()

                Dim ds As New IO.Compression.DeflateStream(ms, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
                ds.CopyTo(msOut)

                Dim strPath As String = "d:\fsout\" + strDBName

                If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(strPath)) Then
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strPath)
                End If

                Dim file As New FileStream(strPath + "\" + strFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                msOut.WriteTo(file)
                file.Close()
                ms.Close()

                ds.Close()
```

I'd love to be able to do this in PHP though. Anyone know a trick to decompress the file in PHP? I have a feeling it's something to do with 'unpack()' in php but not sure which parameters to use.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question

.NET uses zlib to do the compression in IO.Compression.DeflateStream()

So what I needed to do is this:

```
$uncompressed = zlib_decode($X);
echo $uncompressed;
```

Actually a lot easier in php than VB.

My full code would be:

```
 <?php
//assume that I already made the connection

$sql = "SELECT [FileData], [contentType] FROM dbo.Files where [FileGUID]='DAB88A50-E2C3-E311-A2D2-005056930304'";

$stmt= sqlsrv_query($conn , $sql);


if( $stmt === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}

$result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$filename = "test.pdf";
$X = $result['FileData'];

$contentType=  $result['ContentType'];
$filename=  $result['Filename'];


header("Content-Type:    $contentType; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");  //File name extension was wrong
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");



//$X =  unpack('H*hex', $X);

echo $X;

?>
```